# Get and return firestore collections in react native

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native

I just started learning to react native and firebase, so I want to get all collections from firestore, but the problem is when I want to return data they give me **undefined** even when I use async/await

```
async getAllAssistances() {

            let allAssistances;

            const  assistances = await firebase.firestore().collection('assistances')
            assistances.get().then((querySnapshot :any) => {
                const tempDoc = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc:any) => {
                  return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
                })
               console.log('====================================');
               console.log(tempDoc);
               console.log('====================================');

                allAssistances = tempDoc;
              })
        

      
            console.log('********************************');
            console.log(allAssistances);
            console.log('********************************');


            return allAssistances;
    }


// Output : 


====================================
Array [
  Object {
    "city": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "id": "0N0iYx8RCPPSIEXfUQUk",
    "latitude": 1,
    "longitude": 1,
    "nbPlaces": 1,
  },
]
====================================


********************************
undefined
********************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `await` on the `collection`, which is not actually an asynchronous function. But you're using `.then()` on the `.get()`, which is . You should use `await` for that function.

```
async getAllAssistances() {
   const assistances = firebase.firestore().collection('assistances')
   const querySnapshot = await assistances.get()
   const tempDoc = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc:any) => {
     return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
   })
   console.log('====================================');
   console.log(tempDoc);
   console.log('====================================');
   const allAssistances = tempDoc;

   console.log('********************************');
   console.log(allAssistances);
   console.log('********************************');
   return allAssistances;
}
```